# Where can I find a list of Mozilla Firefox keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: firefox

Where can I find the key combinations for some actions, in Mozilla Firefox? For example, Ctrl+L moves the cursor to the address bar. I wanna move the cursor in the Google search box, from the right-top position. Which key is associated with this? And some other key combinations?

Comment: Hi Roger, welcome to Super User. Some of the shortcuts you want are listed at the other question. To keep the site clean, I hope others will post any other shortcuts at that other question too.

Comment: you posted this question to our sister site, Stack Overflow, and it was migrated here.  in the future, please don't crosspost; questions can be migrated between Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User as necessary.  i've merged the two copies together this time, but if you'll register your account here and associate it with your Stack Overflow account, future questions that get migrated will transfer ownership correctly.

Answer (score 2):

#### See

- [Keyboard shortcuts](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard+shortcuts)

Comment: This [table](http://www.7is7.com/software/firefox/shortcuts.html) is more comprehensive I think. I don't know the site, but the shortcuts for linux work, as far as I tested.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl - E` will put the focus in the search box. Have you [googled](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=firefox+keyboard+shortcuts&aq=0&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=firefox+k&gs_rfai=) it?

Comment: Ctrl/Command-K is a better known shortcut.